# Copy a record and write to xml twice using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, apply-templates

I need to copy my xml record twiceusing XSL't can any 1 guide me with it.
The xml looks like

`<data>
    <record>
    <a>ABC</a>
    <b>ABC</b>
    <c>ARUN</c>
    <d>JAY</d>
    <e>SHREE</e>
    <f>MAKU</f>
    <z>MACK</z>
    </record>
    </data>`

The condition is IF(a=b) then we have to create two records i.e a,b,c,d,e,z
and second record i.e a,b,c,d,f,z . and IF(a!=b) than only 1 record i.e a,b,c,d,f,z.
i have completed the latter part but can't write record twice.

My XSL looks like:-

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="data/record">
<xsl:value-of select='a'/>
<xsl:value-of select='b'/>
<xsl:value-of select='c'/>
<xsl:value-of select='d'/>
<xsl:variable name="A" select='a'/>
<xsl:variable name="B" select='b'/>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$A = $B">
<xsl:call-template name="test" />
</xsl:when> 
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select='f'/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:value-of select='z'/>
</xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template name="test">
<xsl:value-of select='e'/>
<br/>
<xsl:value-of select='f'/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`
```

Can any1 help me with writing the record twice.

Comment: Please post the expected output (in both cases). It's not at all clear what is your type of output (HTML? text?) and what is a "record" (e.g. what separates between two records?).

Comment: My expected output would be as follows:-1st Record ABC,ABC,ARUN,JAY,SHREE,MACK.

2nd Record
ABC,ABC,ARUN,JAY,MAKU,MACK.                                            XML or Text wont matter much for me,

Answer (score 0):

> My expected output would be as follows:-1st Record
>   ABC,ABC,ARUN,JAY,SHREE,MACK. 2nd Record ABC,ABC,ARUN,JAY,MAKU,MACK.

That doesn't answer my question what separates between the records. Assuming your output is text, and each record is on its own line, you could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="data/record">
        <xsl:if test="a = b">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(a, b, c, d, e, z)"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(a, b, c, d, f, z)"/>
        <xsl:if test="position != last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

resulting in:

```
ABCABCARUNJAYSHREEMACK
ABCABCARUNJAYMAKUMACK
```

in your example.

---

### Edit:

Although concatenation is trivial, you may want to minimize the effort by pre-computing the common parts of the two records:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:variable name="sep">, </xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="data/record">
        <xsl:variable name="common-start">
             <xsl:value-of select="concat(a, $sep, b, $sep, c, $sep, d, $sep)"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="common-end">
             <xsl:value-of select="concat($sep, z, '&#10;')"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="a = b">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($common-start, e, $common-end)"/>
        </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($common-start, f, $common-end)"/>
        <xsl:if test="position != last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael,,,,,,but actually the xml in the above sample is just for the refeence,In reality i have to map many records like dis so i was thinking a way wherein i write it completely and for second time i call-template (or any other XSLt function to do that).Nice to learn a very simplified solution anyways.

Comment: @rohit31dec91 Sorry, I am afraid I don't understand.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772035/copy-a-record-and-write-it-twice-after-manipulation)  Refer this to get a context of what needs to be done.

Comment: @rohit31dec91 The reason why I won't fix your XSLT is that it makes no sense to me. I don't think you understand what the translate() function does - and I don't understand what's wrong with the solution I have suggested. Nevertheless, I have edited my answer and added another option for you to consider.

Comment: I know the case study was quite a bit complicated,,,but XSLT's were prepared for my case in the begining,,,i hv no option but to modify for only one feild which i need to replace.And to your question about translate() functn,,,,i couldnt find any function which could replace a element,,,,

Comment: The solution where u make common begining and end would be helpful for my case i guess:)

Answer (score 0):

If you really did want to use a "call-template", then here is some XSLT you could use. It use a named-template where you pass in the nodes you wish to appear in each record.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="data">
   <xsl:for-each select="record">
       <xsl:if test="a=b">
           <xsl:call-template name="record">
               <xsl:with-param name="fields" select="a|b|c|d|e|z" />
           </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:if>
       <xsl:call-template name="record">
           <xsl:with-param name="fields" select="a|b|c|d|f|z" />
       </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="record">
   <xsl:param name="fields" />
   <xsl:for-each select="$fields">
       <xsl:if test="position() != 1">,</xsl:if>
       <xsl:value-of select="." />
   </xsl:for-each>
   <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please note that this will only output the elements in document order, regardless of the order you "select" them in the **xsl:with-param**. That is to say doing this...

```
 <xsl:with-param name="fields" select="a|b|c|d|e|z" />
```

... will yield exactly the same output as this....

```
<xsl:with-param name="fields" select="z|e|d|c|b|a" />
```

Alternatively, you write the statement like so

```
<xsl:with-param name="fields" select="*[not(self::f)]" />
```